# cordova application and localStorage

Tags: html, cordova, session, local-storage

i'm using html5 localStorage, to shares information between pages in a cordova application, but when i try to retrive a variable i get 'undefined' instead of the value.

Here's the code:

page 1:

```
 78             $('#submit').click(function(){
 79                 $.ajax({
 80                     url: 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/login',
 81                   type: 'POST',
 82                     data: JSON.stringify(dt),
 83                     cache: false,
 84                     success: function(data){
 85                         localStorage['id'] = data.id;
 86                         localStorage['name'] = data.name;
 87                         localStorage['surname'] = data.surname;

 ...... some other localStorage variables

 93                     },
 94                     error: function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
 95                         alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
 96                     }
 97                 });
 98
 99                 if (localStorage != null){
100                         window.location='index-logged.html';
101                     }
102             });
```

Now, the page index-logged.html contains the following code:

```
 51         <script>
 52             alert(localStorage['id']);
 53             alert(localStorage['name']);
 54         </script>
```

The result of the alerts are 10 for the id (even if i change the code in the firs page with:

```
85                         localStorage['id'] = 2;
```

I keep getting 10 as result, and the second variable 'name' is always undefined. What am I missing?

EDIT: in firefox the console print this error:

```
uncaught exception: out of memory
```

Comment: I'm not sure if Cordova extends the `Storage` interface or something, but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage), you might want to use [`localStorage.setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) instead.

Comment: I tried with localStorage.setItem('test', 'test'); and localStorage.getItem('test); but i simple get null as result..!

Answer (score 0):

```
cache: false,
```

Maybe this is problem, try cache true.

Answer (score 0):

lets analyse your problem. I build a small testapp for that to reproduce your issue (let me say: i couldn't reproduce that).

This is the code from my index.html (i just installed the console plugin for logging, nothing else).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script>
            function bar() {
                localStorage.item = 1;
                console.log(localStorage.item);
            }

            function barfoo() {
                localStorage.item = 0;
                console.log(localStorage.item);
            }

            function bar1() {
                localStorage['id'] = 1;
                console.log(localStorage['id']);
            }

            function barfoo1() {
                localStorage['id'] = 0;
                console.log(localStorage['id']);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foobarContainer">
            <button id="foo" onclick="bar()">Set localStorage.item to 1</button><br>
            <button id="foobar" onclick="barfoo()">Set localStorage.item to 0</button>
        </div><!-- closing div of foobarContainer -->
        <div id="foobarContainer2">
            <button id="foo1" onclick="bar1()">Set localStorage['id'] to 1</button><br>
            <button id="foobar1" onclick="barfoo1()">Set localStorage['id'] to 0</button>
        </div><!-- closing div of foobarContainer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

So like you see, i tried booth. The solution you tried and the solution given by Passerby (i thought first that passerby is right but he isn't. `['id']` works also like a charme.

By pressing the buttons one after the other my console logs 1 - 0 - 1 - 0. I checked my local storage, and it looks also fine. 
[image: LocalStorage]

I don't know which program you use for debugging your apps but i would recommend you to use [GapDebug](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.genuitec.com%2Fproducts%2Fgapdebug%2F&ei=ZNM0VcqeAcepsAGqioDYAg&usg=AFQjCNGWG9BXMF36KQ_bWOEXNWpMyPXtRg&bvm=bv.91071109,d.bGg) for that. It's free of charge and there never was a greater tool then that.

So there might be a problem with your array `data` - can you post the whole content of that array? And download GapDebug, you can check your localStorage with that and many many more things!

We'll try to figure out, where your problem is. I'll help you with that.

**In light of the fact that the user has commented, here my edit and my function**

```
function getDataProfile()
{ 
var term=null;
$.ajax({
        url:'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?key={'+apiKey+'}&access_token='+localStorage.accessToken,
        type:'GET',
        data:term,
        dataType:'json',
        error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
        },
        success:function(data)
            {
                 localStorage.analyticsSecondName=data.items[1].name; 
                 localStorage.analyticsLogin="true"; 
                 localStorage.analyticsAccountID=data.items[1].id; 
                }
            });
      setTimeout(getProps, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I almost solved the problem thanks to your example. Looks like i can't set localStorage variable inside an ajax function. In fact if i call the function to set/get localStorage OUTSIDE the ajax call, evertything's fine!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. But that sounds a bit mysterious because i'm doing exactly the same like you did in an application i developed 2 month ago. I get back a json array from the google api. I'll do an edit to my post and i'm going to add one of my functions.

Comment: If i copy the correct code inside the success ajax function nothing works..! It's really annoying. I can't really do what you did with the google analytics..

Comment: Did you pick the correct depth of the data array? Like data.item.x? Is it realy data.id etc? Are you able to send me the whole project? I could try to debug that. support@cordova-forum.de if you're able to.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that success function is fired? In my project i use syntax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '',
    ....
}).done( function( data ){
   ..........
   ..........
}).fail(function( jqXHR,text_status,strError ){
   ..........
   ..........
});
```

according to jQ docs: '*The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.*'